# Difference between raw pointers and weak references in Vala?

Tags: memory, vala

**(1)** What's the difference between **weak references**, like

```
weak SomeType weak_ref = hard_ref;
```

or

```
unowned SomeType unowned_ref = hard_ref;
```

on the one hand and **raw pointers** like

```
SomeType* raw_ptr = hard_ref;
```

on the other, **from a practical point of view**?

At first, I though that weak references get reset automatically to `null`, as they do in Java, but they clearly don't. The docs only compare weak and hard references, but they don't mention raw pointers. Am I missing something?

**(2)** Furthermore:

- *Are* there any concepts in Vala which allow resetting a weak reference or raw pointer automatically to `null` when the referenced object is finalized?
- And *are* there any counterparts for classes like `WeakHashMap` or the `Collections.newSetFromMap` function from Java available in Vala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few differences between weak references and raw pointers:

- You can call `delete` on a raw pointer but not a weak reference.
- Raw pointers can be stacked but references can't (*i.e.*, you can have `Foo**`, but there's no equivalent of that for references.
- If a type can be copied or reference counted, sensible things happen when you assign a weak reference to a strong reference. With raw pointers, memory management is entirely up to you.

You can create a collection of weak pointers (*e.g.*, `ArrayList<unowned FileStream>`). Java's `WeakHashMap` is based on there being a garbage collector and there is no garbage collector in Vala. References go out of scope and get cleaned up deterministically rather than as the result of memory pressure.

It sounds like what you want is C++'s `std::weak_ptr`. Vala has [`WeakRef`](https://valadoc.org/gobject-2.0/GLib.WeakRef), which is similar. A `WeakRef` can hold a possibly disposed pointer and will return a strong reference to it or null on request. It only works for classes that derive from `GLib.Object` though. Unlike the C++ version, it sadly isn't statically type-safe (though it is run-time type-safe).

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification. To my understanding, a `weak` reference in Vala is best compared to a simple reference in C++, plus the "sensible things" which you mentioned. The `WeakRef` from `GLib` is indeed what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My own understanding at present is:

- Pointers - one of the advantages of Vala is it maintains the C ABI. This is good for using and writing shared libraries. Vala provides for both the indirection operator, *, and address-of operator, &, that exist in C. I don't think these should normally be used in Vala code, but should be used in the rare cases when you need to do something unusual with a C library or you want to write code that manages its own memory
- Ownership - both C and Vala use block scope for variables, Vala provides a nice advantage over C through its assisted memory management. This means, that unlike C, heap allocated resources don't need to be manually freed. Note that "freeing" includes decrementing the reference count of an object. If you want to switch off this behaviour in Vala then mark the variable as unowned, this means Vala makes no attempt to free the resources at the end of the block. Because Vala generates C code the C compiler will still automatically free any stack allocated variables in the block, but Vala will not produce the additional code for de-allocating heap memory or reducing a reference count. In most cases Vala makes the sensible choice, but you may have to do this for constant strings returned by a function call. So they are marked as unowned because the memory doesn't need to be freed
- Weak references - this is mainly used to avoid two way references causing cycles in reference counting, a detailed explanation is given in [Vala's Memory Management Explained](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ReferenceHandling) . The example there is a doubly-linked list